# How a patch to display the number of times that turtles have visited it?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to show how many times a patch has been visited by turtles after the simulation.

```
ask patches with [pcolor = lime] [ 
  if count turtles-here > 0 
    [set counter (counter + 1)]   
  set plabel counter
]
```

Something looks like that. Each patch's value will be increased when a turtle visit it. In the end of simulation, each patch will show the different number of times that turtles have visited it. Thanks.

Comment: If 5 turtles all visit the same patch at the same time, is that 5 visits, or 1 visit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution seems fine.  You just need to give patches a `counter` attribute.  For example,

```
patches-own [counter]

to setup
  ask n-of 50 patches [set pcolor lime sprout 1]
  ask patches [count-visits]
end

to go
  ask turtles [move-to one-of patches]
  ask patches [count-visits]
end

to count-visits  ;; patch proc
  if (pcolor = lime) [ 
    if count turtles-here > 0 [
      set counter (counter + 1)
    ]
  set plabel counter
  ] 
end
```

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you very much for your reply. It works now. I could not figured it out before because I would want turtles to stay on the patch for 60 ticks, and the plabel always display the number that is greater than 60. So I now use a condition (if count turtles-here > 0 and count-down = 1) to fix this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alan, is it possible to turn patches with those numbers into gradients colour in terms of visits? For example, 1 visit could be light green, 5 visits could be green and 10 visits should be dark green. I am not sure if NetLogo Palette Extension would work in this case. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Please open a new question.